# SQL Server: Adjusting queried date range based on current date and adjust column headers as well

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I have a query to pull number of patient seen from our medical record system by provider for certain time periods.  I'd like to pull each month for the last year including the current month to date.

I can make a query to do this manually, but I want this to auto-adjust each month so that the current month is the last query and the other months are the precending 11 months without having to redo all the searches in code.

Ideally, I'd also want this to output into my table with the appropriate headers for which month it was.  For example, this month would list as 9/15 instead of Month12 when the table was outputted and this would adjust to 10/15 next month as so forth.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish these two tasks?

Here is my current code, which works perfectly but has to be adjusted manually every month:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Output (Provider, Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4, Date5, Date6, Date7, Date8, Date9, Date10, Date11, Date12)
OUTPUT inserted.Provider, inserted.Date1, inserted.Date2, inserted.Date3, inserted.Date4, inserted.Date5, inserted.Date6, inserted.Date7, inserted.Date8,
inserted.Date9, inserted.Date10,inserted.Date11, inserted.Date12
select pm.last_name,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20141001' and enc_timestamp  < '20141101' then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Oct14,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20141101' and enc_timestamp  < '20141201' then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Nov14,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20141201' and enc_timestamp  < '20150101' then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Dec14,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20150101' and enc_timestamp  < '20150201' then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Jan15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20150201' and enc_timestamp  < '20150301' then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Feb15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20150301' and enc_timestamp  < '20150401' then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Mar15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20150401' and enc_timestamp  < '20150501' then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_April15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20150501' and enc_timestamp  < '20150601' then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_May15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20150601' and enc_timestamp  < '20150701' then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_June15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20150701' and enc_timestamp  < '20150801' then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_July15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20150801' and enc_timestamp  < '20150901' then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Aug15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= '20150901' and enc_timestamp  < '20151001' then 1 else 0 end) as Total_Charge_Sep15
from patient_encounter pe
inner join provider_mstr pm ON pe.rendering_provider_id = pm.provider_id
where enc_timestamp >= '20140101' and enc_timestamp  < '20160101' and billable_ind = 'Y' and checkin_datetime is not NULL
group by pm.last_name
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method DATEADD is your friend:

EDIT: Get the first day of the current month as ReferenceDate autommatically:
EDIT2: Set the reference date one year back.

```
DECLARE @ReferenceDate DATETIME=CAST(YEAR(GETDATE())-1 AS VARCHAR(4))+REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE()),2),' ','0')+'01';
```

And this is your adapted code:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Output (Provider, Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4, Date5, Date6, Date7, Date8, Date9, Date10, Date11, Date12)
OUTPUT inserted.Provider, inserted.Date1, inserted.Date2, inserted.Date3, inserted.Date4, inserted.Date5, inserted.Date6, inserted.Date7, inserted.Date8,
inserted.Date9, inserted.Date10,inserted.Date11, inserted.Date12
select pm.last_name,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= @ReferenceDate and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,1,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Oct14,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,1,@ReferenceDate) and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,2,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Nov14,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,2,@ReferenceDate) and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,3,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Dec14,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,3,@ReferenceDate) and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,4,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Jan15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,4,@ReferenceDate) and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,5,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Feb15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,5,@ReferenceDate) and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,6,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Mar15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,6,@ReferenceDate) and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,7,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_April15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,7,@ReferenceDate) and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,8,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_May15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,8,@ReferenceDate) and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,9,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_June15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,9,@ReferenceDate) and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,10,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_July15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,10,@ReferenceDate) and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,11,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as total_patients_Aug15,
  SUM(case when enc_timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,11,@ReferenceDate) and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(MONTH,12,@ReferenceDate) then 1 else 0 end) as Total_Charge_Sep15
from patient_encounter pe
inner join provider_mstr pm ON pe.rendering_provider_id = pm.provider_id
where enc_timestamp >= @ReferenceDate and enc_timestamp  < DATEADD(YEAR,2,@ReferenceDate) and billable_ind = 'Y' and checkin_datetime is not NULL
group by pm.last_name
END
```

Comment: @Reid, oh, sorry, I did not see your "adjust column headers as well"... This is impossible to get with "normal" SQL. There are two ways: dynamic SQL (meaning to build the whole statement within a VARCHAR-variable where you can set the column's names, and execute this with EXEC. Better (at least in my eyes) would be, to set the  columns to unspecified names (month1,month2,...) and do the naming within your GUI.

Comment: @Reid, glad to help you! If you like this answer, please upvote and accept it. All answerers are hungry for reputation points :-)

Comment: Looks like this was set up to make the current month first, and then add future months after!  I assume it should be staring with DATEADD(MONTH,-11)@ReferenceDate) for the first column, and work down through -10, -9, etc until you just get @ReferenceDate?

Comment: @Reid, yes, thanks for pointing this out... All depends on ReferenceDate. Just set it one year back an all is fine, I'll edit my answer in a second...

Comment: @Reid, done! You can "move" the reference date simply by adding a constant to the year or the month part...

Comment: Thanks!  Also, one less edit that I can make myself, but the date is still off by 1 month.  This shows LAST month as the most current and fails to check this month for Month 12.  But thank you!

Comment: @Reid: Just adapt this part (look at the +1): REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())+1,2). With GETDATE() you get the current date, MONTH(ofDate) comes back with the numeric month's index. If you add or subtract any constant there (same with the year!) you can shift this date whereever you want.